# ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sql-update, ibatis

I am using iBATIS from my application. this error is thrown:

```
operation; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [72000]; error code [1461];   
--- The error occurred in com/syngenta/panda/dao/sqlmap/shared/Task.xml.  
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the TaskSQLMap.updateTask-InlineParameterMap.  
--- Check the statement (update failed).  
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

the query I am using is

```
UPDATE TASK
        SET
        TIME_CONSUMED = #timeConsumed#, TIME_SUBMITTED = #timeSubmitted# , TIME_COMPLETED = #timeCompleted# , TASK_STATUS_UID = #status.id#, FAILURE_REASON = #failureReason#
        WHERE
        TASK_UID = #id#
```

there is no long type for all properties inserted, however there is a long type for another property that is not included in the update statement. and there is no LONG type for all columns in the table. can you please help

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include the definition of the TASK table? Also - have you checked TaskSQLMap.updateTask-InlineParameterMap to be certain that LONG wasn't accidentally used for a non-LONG column? (Remember - `LONG` in Oracle means something totally different than `long` in Java). Thanks.

Comment: For Oracle, "LONG" means "much data" in this case and can refer to BLOB,CLOB columns and even to VARCHAR(40) columns if the actual values exceed the 40 characters.

Comment: can you please add this as an answer and I'll accept it.